# Discrepancy between log_prob and manual calculation

Tags: python, pytorch

I want to define multivariate normal distribution with mean `[1, 1, 1]` and variance covariance matrix with `0.3` on diagonal. After that I want to calculate log likelihood on datapoints `[2, 3, 4]`

**By torch distributions**

```
import torch
import torch.distributions as td

input_x = torch.tensor([2, 3, 4])
loc = torch.ones(3)
scale = torch.eye(3) * 0.3
mvn = td.MultivariateNormal(loc = loc, scale_tril=scale)
mvn.log_prob(input_x)
tensor(-76.9227)
```

**From scratch**

By using formula for log likelihood:

[image]

We obtain tensor:

```
first_term = (2 * np.pi* 0.3)**(3)
first_term = -np.log(np.sqrt(first_term))
x_center = input_x - loc
tmp = torch.matmul(x_center, scale.inverse())
tmp = -1/2 * torch.matmul(tmp, x_center)
first_term + tmp 
tensor(-24.2842)
```

where I used fact that [image]

My question is - what's the source of this discrepancy?

Comment: That `.sum()` was redundent. Without it I obtain scalar, and discrepancy still exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the covariance matrix to the `scale_tril` instead of `covariance_matrix`. From the docs of [PyTorch's Multivariate Normal](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/distributions.html#multivariatenormal)

> scale_tril (Tensor) – lower-triangular factor of covariance, with positive-valued diagonal

So, replacing `scale_tril` with `covariance_matrix` would yield the same results as your manual attempt.

```
In [1]: mvn = td.MultivariateNormal(loc = loc, covariance_matrix=scale)
In [2]: mvn.log_prob(input_x)
Out[2]: tensor(-24.2842)
```

However, it's more efficient to use `scale_tril` according to the authors:

> ...Using scale_tril will be more efficient:

You can calculate the lower choelsky using [`torch.linalg.cholesky`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.linalg.cholesky.html#torch.linalg.cholesky)

```
In [3]: mvn = td.MultivariateNormal(loc = loc, scale_tril=torch.linalg.cholesky(scale))
In [4]: mvn.log_prob(input_x)
Out[4]: tensor(-24.2842)
```